# Render dynamically vertical tabs and set classes depends on if statement

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, haml

I would like to refactor code below and get rid of if statements for classes from view.

```
.container
  .tabbable.tabs-left
    %ul.nav.nav-tabs
      - @related_tasks.each do |task|
        %li{class: ("active" if @task == task)}
          = link_to task.name, "#tab#{task.id}", data: { toggle: 'tab' }, class: @current_user_tasks.include?(task.id) ? '' : 'inactive' 

    .tab-content
      - @related_tasks.each do |task|
        .tab-pane{id: "tab#{task.id}", class: ("active" if @task == task)}
          = render 'task_tab', task: task
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Helper methods are good for this.  In your view's helper file:

```
def task_link_class(task)
  if @current_user_tasks.include?(task)
    ''
  else
    'inactive'
  end
end
```

Some would prefer the trinary operator instead:

```
def task_link_class(task)
  @current_user_tasks.include?(task) ? '' : 'inactive'
end
```

And in your view:

```
= link_to task.name, "#tab#{task.id}", data: { toggle: 'tab' }, class: task_link_class(task)
```

Comment: Its my understanding that using `@instance_variables` in helpers is not a good practice. Better pass values as arguments.

Comment: @tokland, Thanks for pointing that out.  Do you have a link where I can learn why?

Comment: @tokland, How about this?  http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/27-replace-instance-variable-with-local-variable

Comment: Yes, that would be the idea, in partials, in helpers, etc, use arguments. The key is reusability, this way you can use and tests those functions in isolation.